# How to check if a selected number is in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-markers

I want to place markers on a google map with filtering. If the filter only needs to check a single value, my code will work fine. However, if I want to check if the value returned by the filter is in that array, then unfortunately the code doesn't work.

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/7o8w2eaq/

So the code snippet I would like help with:

```
filterMarkersEres = function (eres) {
  for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    var ereshonap = marker.eres;
    let igaze = ereshonap.includes(eres);
    //ereshonap.includes(eres);
    console.log(igaze);

    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (ereshonap.includes(eres) || eres.length === 0) {
      //
      marker.setVisible(true);
    }
    // Categories don't match
    else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
};
```

So I want to make the ripening time filter work for several months. I think I should somehow check if "marker.eres" contains the value of the selected month, but I can't figure out how.So I want to ask for help with this.

I hope I have said it clearly, thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the data type of elements in array, (which array ?); what is the data type of item passed to `.includes()` ?

Comment: `eres` is in form of a string. please try `let igaze = ereshonap.includes(parseInt(eres));` and `if (ereshonap.includes(parseInt(eres)) || eres.length === 0) {`

Comment: you can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/a9my56z0/ Selecting JUNE, for instance, shows the filter in action

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it already works based on the comments!

As pointed out by [@GrafiCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72262300/how-to-check-if-a-selected-number-is-in-an-array/72262847#comment127668156_72262300), the `ereshonap` array contained numbers, while `eres` was a string. Therefore, I needed to convert the string to an integer using `parseInt(eres)` before checking if it was in the array.

```js
filterMarkersEres = function (eres) {
  for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    var ereshonap = marker.eres;

    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (ereshonap.includes(parseInt(eres)) || eres.length === 0) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
    } else { // Categories don't match
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the console.log(variable.isArray()); if true then its and array else if false then non array